# How can we get table name from inside trigger?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, trigger

I need to pass the table name from trigger to procedure.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trg_ProjectCreation] 
   ON  [dbo].[Projects] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
 -- procedure call 
    exec Proc_Test @Tablename (not need to hardcode)
END
```

I want to know is there any way I can get table name from trigger itself. I need this to be dynamic because when the table's name changes I don't want to change my code.

Comment: Why don't you just set the variable manually in the trigger?  Is it because you are auto-generating the triggers?

Comment: No, I want to write common logic in procedure for all table base on Information_Schema

Comment: But a trigger always belongs to exactly ony table (at least in SQL Server). So there is no point making the tablename dynamic (and the tablename is already "hardcoded" in the `alter trigger` part)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if somehow table name will change i need to change my code if I put table name "hardcoded".

Comment: and since you would need to change all references to that table why is that a problem? Personally it is rare to ever change a table name in a good design. If you are thinking about changing names, then you probably need to rethink that.

Comment: @HLGEM - Yes you are right, but I just made my code dynamic so for every table i don't need to right specific hard code value for table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might not be the best approach to dealing for your problem, but it will certainly achieve the stated goal.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trg_ProjectCreation] ON  [dbo].[Projects] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    declare @TableName sysname
    select @tablename = object_schema_name(parent_id) + '.' + object_name(parent_id) 
    from sys.triggers where object_id = @@PROCID

    exec dbo.myProcedure @Tablename 
END
GO
```

A better option may be to change the way the trigger is created, and putting the name down manually (if it fits your scenario), for e.g.:

```
declare @tablename sysname, @sql nvarchar(max)
set @tablename = '[dbo].[myTableName]'
set @sql = 'ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trg_ProjectCreation] ON  ' + @tablename + ' 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    exec dbo.myProcedure ' + @tablename + '
END
GO'
exec sp_executeSQL @sql
```